# How do I get JavaScript functions in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've done Java for a while now and am moving to web development- I am having some troubles however, My code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">

    var getHeight = function() {

        return $(window).height();

    }

</script>
```

I want to get the height of the window here,

```
img.pos_fixed {

        position:fixed;
        top:getHeight() / 2;
        right:250px;

    }
```

but it does not display in the middle of the screen. I am very new so please don't bash on me that I should learn html/javascript/css as I already am.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same thing. Please edit your tags.

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Comment: Looks like you're question is about JavaScript and CSS and has nothing to do with Java or HTML (as the title suggests).

Comment: Just use JavaScript to set the style dynamically. It looks lke you already know how to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could close your jquery script tag,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

and use pure css

```
img.pos_fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    right:250px;
}
```

**Edit**

Alternative with JavaScript, you should probably wait for `document.ready` -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img.pos_fixed").css('top','50%'); // same css
});
```

Comment: Thank you- the pure css worked for me :) Website isn't letting me set this answer as 'the' answer, says I have to wait 5 minutes :p

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to call javascript functions from css.

Instead you'll have to set the css from within javascript:

```
var obj= document.createElement('img');
obj.style.top = getHeight() / 2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$("img.pos_fixed").css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '50%', 'right': '250px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the jquery library in a separate script tag like this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Write your jquery code in another script tag then.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getHeight = function(){
        return $(window).height();
    }
    var img_height = getHeight/2;
</script>
```

You can set CSS from script itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("img.pos_fixed").css('top',img_height);
</script>
```

You can put the rest of the styles in a style tag.

```
<style>
    img.pos_fixed {
        position:fixed;
        right:250px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can not use `javascript` function inside `css` code. but you can change any `css` of an element using `jquery/javascript`. if you want to place the `image` in the middle of the screen from top than you can do that by only `css`. no need to use `javascript`.

```
<img class="middle_img" src="https://www.ourkidssports.com/js/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/football_public_domain.jpg" alt="football">
<style type="text/css">
    .middle_img{
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        position:fixed;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
    }
</style>
```

here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/banded_krait/Cv3ny/

NB: `position:fixed;` will fixed the image to the screen. it will not scroll if you scroll your page.